# How to set Origin Company (author) in Open XML SDK 2.5 for excel?

Tags: xml, excel, properties, sdk

I can set a lot of properties for the document through the `.PackageProperties`, but I can't find the Company part?

```
public SpreadsheetDocument CreateDocument(string path)
    {
        m_Document = SpreadsheetDocument.Create(path, SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook);
        FilePath = path;

        // create the workbook
        WorkbookPart workbookPart = m_Document.AddWorkbookPart();
        workbookPart.Workbook = new Workbook();     // create the worksheet
        WorksheetPart worksheetPart = workbookPart.AddNewPart<WorksheetPart>();
        worksheetPart.Worksheet = new Worksheet();

        // create sheet data
        SheetData sheetData = new SheetData();
        worksheetPart.Worksheet.AppendChild(sheetData);

        //// save worksheet
        //worksheetPart.Worksheet.Save();

        //add sheets container
        Sheets sheets = new Sheets();
        workbookPart.Workbook.AppendChild(sheets);
        workbookPart.Workbook.Save();

        //add default styles
        m_StyleHelper.AttachToDocument(m_Document);

        //set properties
        m_Document.PackageProperties.Subject = "Statistics sub";
        m_Document.PackageProperties.Creator = "c1";

        m_Document.PackageProperties.Created = DateTime.Now;
        m_Document.PackageProperties.Modified = DateTime.Now;
        m_Document.PackageProperties.LastModifiedBy = "lmb1";
        m_Document.PackageProperties.Category = "Statistics1";
        m_Document.PackageProperties.Description = "Statistics2";            
        m_Document.PackageProperties.Title = "Title1";


        return m_Document;
    }
```

[image]

I have searched high and low, but with no luck :(

Thanks in advance!

Simon

Answer (score 2):

I finally figured it out, Company is set in the `.ExtendedFilePropertiesPart` as follows:

```
m_Document.AddExtendedFilePropertiesPart();
m_Document.ExtendedFilePropertiesPart.Properties = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.ExtendedProperties.Properties();
m_Document.ExtendedFilePropertiesPart.Properties.Company = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.ExtendedProperties.Company("My Company");
```